# IFFT confusion, sampling frequency

Tags: fft, matlab, frequency-domain, ifft, time-domain

I made a previous post about what I am trying to do

[Previous Post](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/86900/ifft-gives-complex-values-in-matlab)

I have band-limited data in the frequency domain from a VNA and I am trying to convert it into the time domain. VNA data saved in .s2p in Real/Imaginary format

VNA settings:

[image]

I extend the data to create a complete FFT. Zero padding is used for this procedure
For sampling frequency, I use Nyquist

[image]

I make the number of points to be a power of 2

[image]

Zero padding Matlab Pseudo_code as follows:

```
Data_ext=[zeros(3200,1); Data_raw;  zeros(79871,1)]
```

I take this extended data, copy it without the DC point, conjugate it, flip it, and append it. Pseudo_code as follows:

```
Data_copy=Data_ext (2:end)
Data_copy=flip(conj(Data_ext (2:end)))
Data_total=[Data_ext  ;   Data_copy ]
```

[image]

The plot above shows the extended data (single Sided). Top is real, and bottom is imaginary
I can now perform the IFFT on Data_total
From here we can window and filter the data. To match the VNA, we use a Kaiser window (beta=6), and an FIR bandpass filter.

[image]

The plot above shows IFFT results. The black trace is the time domain from the VNA, the blue is the raw IFFT results, and the red is the IFFT windowed and filtered.

**MY ISSUE**
I cannot get the time signal to qualitatively match the VNA. Obviously the VNA probably has some proprietary algorithm, but I should be able to get close. I think that my issue is a lack of understanding of number of points and sample frequency. I have already tried creating my own time domain waveforms, and performing FFT and going back with IFFT. I am hoping that someone is like "Hey dummy, your points need to be XXXX and your Fs should be XXXX"

Comment: Are you 100% sure the time domain VNA matches the frequency domain data you have?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean. I pulled the s2p file and corresponding time domain data

Comment: My question is, when you do your own FFT on the time domain data do you get a match with the frequency data stored in the .s2p files? The reason I’m asking is there’s no point comparing if that’s not the case. In other words, have you tried going the opposite way? As in, take the time domain data, filter it, take the FFT and compare with the .s2p file

Comment: Also, can you share both the .s2p and corresponding time domain data so others can take a crack at it?

Comment: Ah I see what you are saying. My time data is Lin/Mag, so I will need to take some more measurements to get all the mag and phase info.

Comment: (1) The spectrum extends only to $fs/2$ or 8 GHz. You don't need to zero pad between 8 and 16 GHz. (2) Unless you get the phase as well as the magnitude, it will be hard if not impossible to perform the inverse transform.

Comment: @Frank did you ever figure this out?

Comment: @Jdip not quite yet. I got caught writing reports. I have jumped back to this and I am still thoroughly confused.